# add # to every line except those with #

Tags: vi

Using vi

How do i add `#` to every line except those lines already having `#`

`1,$s/^/#/`  help here

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

You could use

```
v/^#/ s/^/#/
```

That's straight from the `ed` editor.  It means "on every line that *does not* start with a `#` character, perform a substitution that inserts a `#` character at the start of the line".

---

Fun fact:  Just like `grep` comes from the `g/re/p` command in `ed` ("print each line matching the regular expression `re`"), so does its `-v` option come from the `v` command in `ed`.  The `v` command works just like `g`, but with the test inverted, so that `v/re/p` prints each line *not matching* the regular expression `re`.

Totally without any references to sources (for now), obviously, but there you go.

Comment: Looks like we both attacked this the same way with different logic (:

Comment: @DopeGhoti Almost.

Answer (score 2):

I'd replace even the existing `#`s (with `#`):

```
1,$s/^#?/#/
```

It replaces `BOL` (Beginning Of Line) followed by 0 or 1 `#`s with `#`.

Comment: I don't think I know what `BOL` is...

Comment: **B**eginning **O**f **L**ine.

Comment: @DopeGhoti Doh. Right.